# Ruby Load error iso8601

Tags: ruby

I am currently working on a chatbot for a wikia plugin. I am using Sactage's code and this can be found here https://github.com/sactage/chatbot-rb . The code i have created is

```
require_relative './client'
require_relative './plugins/auto_tube'
require_relative './plugins/admin'

bot = Chatbot::Client.new
bot.register_plugins(Chatbot::AutoTube, ChatBot::Admin)
bot.run!
```

this would allow the bot to run however i am receving this errror when i attempt to run it on the command line

```
C:/Ruby21-64x/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require': cannot load such file -- iso8601 (LoadError)
      from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
      from C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/AlyssaBot/plugins/auto_tube.rb:2:in '<top (required)>'
      from alyssabot.rb:2:in 'require_relative'
      from alyssabot.rb:2:in '<main>'
```

that is the error that happens when i try to run the file using ruby alyssabot.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace tells you a lot:

```
cannot load such file -- iso8601 (LoadError)
      from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
      from C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/AlyssaBot/plugins/auto_tube.rb:2:in '<top (required)>'
      from alyssabot.rb:2:in 'require_relative'
      from alyssabot.rb:2:in '<main>'
```

First, look for the error, in this case `LoadError`. Ruby can't load a source file, in this case a file named `iso8601.rb` (the `.rb` is omitted).

There is a gem called [`iso8601`](https://rubygems.org/gems/iso8601), which contains a file named [iso8601.rb](https://github.com/arnau/ISO8601/blob/master/lib/iso8601.rb), so you're probably just missing that gem. Can you go back to the tutorial you were reading and see if you were supposed to install that gem?

Comment: thanks for the help i'm still fairly new to writing code. The tutorial made no mention of the gem but installing it did solve the problem thanks again!